# Varios StringTokenizer en una clase

Tags: java

quería saber como puedo poner más de un StringTokenizer. Lo que quiero es que lea un fichero (dentro hay varios \n y ;) y me trocee los contenidos.Y después lo que me dé almacenarlo en una pila, creo que lo primero podría meterlo en un vector y dependiendo de la segunda posición (en este caso deportes) clasificarlo en una u otra pila.
Aquí pongo una parte del fichero: *El Espanyol se estrena en Europa tras conquistar Moscú;deporte;El Espanyol logró un importantísimo triunfo en su visita al CSKA de Moscú correspondiente a la segunda jornada de la fase de grupos de la Europa League;sportyou;11/10/2019*

```
FileReader f = new FileReader(archivo);
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);
StringTokenizer tokens=new StringTokenizer(f, "\n");
```

//Aquí no sabría como poner este contenido ya  troceado en un vector.

```
 StringTokenizer tokens=new StringTokenizer(f, ";");
```

No sé si se podría hacer así, y sobre las pilas en java estoy un poco perdida. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
* En vez de usar 
*/
StringTokenizer tokens=new StringTokenizer(f, "\n");
//usa
String cadena="";
cadena= b.readLine();
//y despues si
StringTokenizer tokens=new StringTokenizer(cadena, ";");
```

Comment: Hola Sergio, gracias por tu contribución, veo que tienes una explicación dentro del código, regularmente las respuestas que son únicamente código se consideran como de "baja calidad", como recomendación, sería bueno que agregaras la explicación fuera del código, revisa otras respuestas en el sitio, saludos.